# Get the days date of a week input

Tags: javascript, date, web, time

the title seems similar to some questions but what I want is different ,

simply I have an input of type "week" ,
I want to make a function that takes the week and returns the date numbers in that week ,

for example function takes **"2020-W46"** (which is the input value of the week input)

and returns
**"2020-11-9 , 2020-11-10 , 2020-11-11 , 2020-11-12 , 2020-11-13 , 2020-11-14 , 2020-11-15 "**

```
function getDaysNumbersInWeek(week){
// stuck here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, where you are having trouble, or ideas that you have to proceed. Any code samples are helpful for people answering you.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+Get+the+days+date+of+a+week+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.